# UITextfield does not respond after addsubview + commitAnimations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewanimation

I am in troubles with a stupid thing :
I have got a view with a nav bar and a table view. 
My nav Bar has a "search" left button. 
When the user pushes this "search" button I want my table view to go down and a new view, dedicated to search, to come between my nav bar and my table view.

- I have got a view controller that simply implement a UITextfield :

  ```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


  @interface serachBox : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> {
       IBOutlet UITextField *kWTextField;     
  } 

  @end
  ```
- My other view controller has my elements (nav bar, table bar ...). Here is the function I use on pushing my search button :

  ```
  - (void) pressSearchBtn:(id)sender{

      [searchBox.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 100)];
      CGRect theFrame = self.view.frame;
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
      [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
      theFrame.origin.y = 100;   
      [self.view addSubview:searchBox.view];
      self.view.frame = theFrame;
      [UIView commitAnimations];

  }
  ```

My problem : my searchbox view appears well but her textfield doesnt respond when I click on it. I tested a simple add subview (without performing the animation stuff) and it works.

What is the matter ?

Answer (score 0):

Hey add this in the pressSearchBtn action towards the end.

[kWTextField becomeFirstResponder];

Comment: This solution, technically speaking, is good but I cannot use it properly for the user experience with my app.

Answer (score 0):

or you could do this. In the Interface Builder put the textfield right on top of the view and not out of the view. Put it at (0,0) with size (320,31). Then in the tools->attributes inspector check the hidden property of the textfield to true. then in the buttonClick put this code.

```
- (void) pressSearchBtn:(id)sender{ 

    kwtextField.alpha = 0;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    kwtextField.hidden = FALSE;
    kwtextField.alpha = 1;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this is not exactly how I'd like it to work. If I do it like this, my UITextField take some space at the top of my view, even if it's hidden. This is not great.

Answer (score 0):

Hey finally I got it done for you.

Put the textfield anywhere on the interface builder, hide it in tools -> attributes inspector.

Do this in you viewDidLoad method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, 580);

    self.view.frame = frame;

    text.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y, 320, 100);

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

then in the btnClick method write this.

```
-(IBAction) btnClicked: (id) sender
{

    CGRect frame1 = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 100); 
    text.hidden = FALSE;
    CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"frame" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    self.text.frame = frame1;
    self.view.frame = frame;
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

cheers!!!